# Clojure - random access where the key itself is complex

Tags: clojure

Vectors are good for random access, but the key is just its position in the sequence, just a number. What about when you want the key itself be something more interesting, and you want fast random access? For this the obvious candidate would seem to be a Map. In most Map examples the keys used are keywords (with two dots at the front). Can I for example use a Vector as a key to a Map? Or not so much 'can', but would this be an idiomatic thing to do? And are there examples of this sort of thing out there? In a way I am thinking in relational database terms, except the structure being kept in memory.

Comment: Have you tried that yet?

Comment: Not yet. Seems like a sensible approach to me, but I'm so used to finding examples on the Internet before I proceed...

Answer (score 2):

I've done this--used other things as keys.  Idiomatic?  Why not?  You can pretty much use anything as a key.  (Maybe others will have a different opinion.)

Lookup will follow Clojure's equality semantics.  The place where that gets interesting is if you want to use a defrecord or a deftype as a key.  These function similarly in some respects, but deftype equality is normally by identity, i.e. `=` is equivalent to `identical?` for deftypes (but see amalloy's comment below).  Functions also have identity semantics, I believe.

```
(defrecord BarRec [x y])

(deftype BarTyp [x y])

(def foo {125 1, 
          "this" 2, 
          {:a 10 :b 20} 3, 
          [1 2 3] 4, 
          (->BarRec 10 20) 5, 
          (BarTyp. 10 20) 6})
```

Notice that I create new instances of each key below:

```
(foo 125) ;=> 1
(foo "this") ;=> 2
(foo {:b 20 :a 10}) ;=> 3
(foo [1 2 3]) ;=> 4
(foo (->BarRec 10 20)) ;=> 5
(foo (->BarTyp 10 20)) ;=> nil
```

The new deftype instance doesn't find the map entry that uses the old deftype instance as a key, even though they have the same contents.  Here's a clue to the reason why:

```
(= (->BarRec 10 20) (->BarRec 10 20)) ;=> true
(= (->BarTyp 10 20) (->BarTyp 10 20)) ;=> false
(def bar-typ (->BarTyp 10 20))
(= bar-typ bar-typ) ;=> true
```

This means that there are situations where using deftypes as keys is much more efficient than using defrecords: Comparing two defrecords requires comparing their contents, while comparing deftypes requires only deciding whether something is the same object--probably by pointer equality.

However, defrecords include lots of conveniences that deftypes don't have.  And defrecords are *Clojurely*.  Equality by strict identity is not *Clojurely*.  Equality by identity is useful if you want to track a data structure whose contents change over time, but that kind of beast is not supposed to be running around wild in the Clojure forest.  You might almost say that deftypes were created with a deprecated status from the beginning (but they will never go away afaik).

(Note: The point about the difference between hashing efficiency for defrecords and deftypes carries over to Java interop.  Both data structures can be treated as Java classes, and when a Java hash map compares two defrecords or two deftypes, it calls `hashCode()` methods that follow the appropriate Clojure semantics.  Using deftypes as hash keys in Java can be a lot faster.)

Comment: I hope to never have to go near a `deftype`. The sequences I need random access to are immutable, coming basically from recursion.

Comment: That's what you're supposed to feel. :-)

Comment: `deftype` equality does not have identity semantics *in general*. You can implement `equals` and `hashCode` on a `deftype`, and then they will behave accordingly as map keys. Only if you do not specify any more meaningful implementation is pointer equality used.

Comment: Ah, thanks @amalloy.  I hadn't realized that.  I've made a small revision to the answer to reflect this point.  Interestingly, one can't do the same thing--override `equals` and `hashCode`--[with defrecord](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/clojure/EdjnSxRkOPk/nl7Mv3Yjc-IJ).  Another way in which `deftype` differs from `defrecord` by allowing more freedom (to potentially shoot oneself in the foot).

Answer (score 0):

I think the reason there are not many examples of Clojure 'random access' is that doing so is not a functional way of programming. If 'everything is a stream' (not so much in the technical sense but in the 'flowing past' sense), then what is needed should already be there.

To fix, an existing stream-producing function in the program could have each of the items it produces 'made greater'. Or two accumulators could be returned from a reduce rather than one:

https://gist.github.com/stathissideris/9500581

In my case I was already creating a stream of positions, and need random access to something else (a Blob). So I made an existing reduce function return elements that had both position and Blob, already next to one another - so no need for the random access to Blob that prompted this question.

Answer (score 0):

You may use objects of all types as keys in Clojure maps. They were designed to support this kind of use. The reason you see maps with keywords so frequently is because they are also the equivalent to data objects in OO languages.